# Angularjs Directive:- scope not defined error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
myApp.directive('qsetAnswer', function(){
  var linker = function(scope,element,attr) {
    console.log(scope.body); // this prints fine.
  };
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope: '=info',
    template: '<h5> ' + scope.body + ' </h5>', // this gives error.
    link: linker
  }
});
```

The above gives:- scope not defined error

Edit:- the problem with `template: '<h5>{{body}}</h5>',` is that my `{{body}}` already contains html ie. `<p> abc </p>` doing it like `template: '{{body}}'` prints `<p> abc </p>` like a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're binding HTML to a template, you can use the ng-bind-html directive.

This assumes you're using **Angular 1.2+**

```
template: '<h5 ng-html-bind="{{body}}"></h5>',
```

For **Angular <1.2**, use

```
template: '<h5 ng-html-bind-unsafe="{{body}}"></h5>',
```

If you run into $sce problems with version 1.2+, read the following:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#nghtmlbindunsafe-has-been-removed-and-replaced-by-nghtmlbind
- [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce)

You can tell Angular to trust your HTML, like so:

```
$scope.ans = $sce.trustAsHtml(' hi <bold> p </bold>');
```

Comment: @SangramSingh Updated again, with $sce example